# how do i make formset required

Tags: python, django, django-forms

How to make all forms in django formset required?  I am using `RequiredFormSet`. But it does not work. Am I missing something? thanks

```
class RequiredFormSet(BaseFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RequiredFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for form in self.forms:
            form.empty_permitted = False
        #self.forms[0].empty_permitted = False

class RecipeIngredientForm(CustomModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = RecipeIngredient
    def clean(self):
        ingredient = self.cleaned_data['ingredient']
        unit = self.cleaned_data['unit']
        if ingredient.ing_type in (ingredient.TYPE_WET, ingredient.TYPE_DRY) and not unit:
            raise forms.ValidationError('unit missing for %s.' % ingredient.name)
        return self.cleaned_data
 RecipeIngredientFormSet = formset_factory(RecipeIngredientForm, formset=RequiredFormSet)
```

UPDATE: Here [traceback](http://dpaste.org/6pD8s/) and here is [my view](http://dpaste.org/YxVfQ/)

Comment: "It doesn't work" isn't a particularly helpful description of your problem. Is there an error/traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ingredient = self.cleaned_data.get('ingredient')
unit = self.cleaned_data.get('unit')
```

This won't raise `KeyError`

UPD.

```
def clean(self):
    ingredient = self.cleaned_data.get('ingredient')
    unit = self.cleaned_data.get('unit') 
    if ingredient is not None and ingredient.ing_type in (ingredient.TYPE_WET, ingredient.TYPE_DRY) and not unit:
        raise forms.ValidationError('unit missing for %s.' % ingredient.name)
    return self.cleaned_data
```

Comment: thanks. But now I am getting `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ing_type'`

Comment: You should check `ingredient` type  (if it is None) before this `if ingredient.ing_type: ...`

Comment: I updated my answer. If you keep on getting errors put tracebacks please

Comment: It worked.thanks alot. You made my day :-).  > I just changed `if ingredient is not None`

Comment: Oh.. it was a typo. You are welcome